# Abstract Factory create objects based on different json format

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstract-factory

We need to create a few types of dynamic metadata base on different json format, for example:
metadata1

```
"metadata1": [{
        "item1": "address1",
        "date": "Jan -Jun22",
        "tag": true,
        "itemurl":"item url"
      }]
}
```

metadata2

```
{
    "amount": 100,
    "item3": {
        "amount:" 1200,
        "currency": "AUD"
      }
    "item4": [
        "blabla",
        "yaliyada"
      ],
    "flag": true,
    "count": 2
}
```

And we have those metadata id, I'm thinking the following implementation

```
public static IMetaData RetrieveMetaData(string metadatDetails, string metadataId)
        {
            switch (metadataId)
            {
                case "metatdata1":
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MetaData1>(metadatDetails);
                case "metatdata2":
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MetaData2>(metadatDetails);
                case "metatdata3":
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MetaData3>(metadatDetails);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

Is there any better implementation using abstract factory? I'm not too familiar with design pattern. I'm thinking to remove switch block, not sure if it's possible.
Thanks for advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it really, well apart from retuning null maybe, but that is a design choice. However there may be other options depending on the exact json contracts

Comment: I agree, this looks OK to me.  I would also stick to using a switch.

Comment: JSON.NET handles this by [emitting a custom `$type` field](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm). You can create your own type converter that inspects some metadata properties and creates the correct object.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to use such a schema though? This makes life really hard for clients. It would be better if you designed a proper schema, actually using JSON Schema and maybe Swagger/OpenAPI, so that clients could know what to expect and even generate DTOs automatically.

Comment: Abstract Factory will not help to parse serialized data, nor will any other GoF design pattern. Consider using an existing library as suggested above. Also consider the Open/Closed principle in any solution you choose.

Comment: We were using dictionary for those sort of dynamic metadata, but they changed the solution to use json blob. I feel it's more difficult for use to convert json to dynamic metadata. but it is what it is. just trying to find the best solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run away from conditional mapping. Either way you will have to have some kind of decision making mechanism with the business logic. It's just an implementation detail whether you determine that from a configuration or in your switch statement.So it's totally good approach in my opinion.
One thing to consider here though is your "default" behavior. Since I'm not familiar with you business logic, can't suggest much, but would advise to pay attention to that and consider maybe throwing an exception there.
Another enhancement may be storing your "metadataId"s somewhere to not use hardcoded strings.